# Firebreath Object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c++, angularjs, firebreath

I have tried to include a FireBreath plugin object in an AngularJS view, however when I try to render the view I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
```

I am able to successfully include the object in the view with `$compile` like this:

```
$("body").append($compile('<object id="plugin" type="application/x-firebreathplugin" width="0" height="0></object>')($scope));
```

However, after including the object like this I cannot get my plugin to fire an event in the JS.

Doing something like this:

```
plugin = document.getElementById('plugin');
console.log(plugin);
```

Returns

```
TypeError
```

In the Chrome console. But I can still do:

```
plugin.callFunction();
```

And have a FireBreath method execute. The issue is when I try to get an event to fire in the JS. No matter what I try, I cannot get the event to fire. So this code will never execute:

```
var addEvent = function(obj, name, func) {
    obj.addEventListener(name, func, false);
}

addEvent(document.getElementById('plugin'), 'firebreathEvent', function(data) {
    console.log('data ' + data);
});

var plugin = document.getElementById('plugin');
plugin.functionThatTriggersFireBreathEvent();
```

Does anybody know if it has something to do with accessing the object after calling `$compile`? I noticed that in regular HTML (before using AngularJS) logging the plugin in the console returns this :

```
<JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object>
```

So I am thinking that whatever I am getting with `document.getElementById` after using `$compile` is not the same.

What would be easier is is if I could just include the `<object>` tag in the view.html file and have it display in `<body class='ng-view'>` but I get the top TypeError, so if anyone has any ideas for that, that would be preferred.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, because I could not get the event to fire, I followed along to this link:

http://colonelpanic.net/2010/12/firebreath-tips-asynchronous-javascript-calls/

(which I think is your blog @taxilian) to get the data back to the JS.

Plugin Code: Great example in the link.

JS Code:

```
//attach FireBreath Object to AngularJS View
$("body").append($compile('<object id="plugin" type="application/x-firebreathplugin" width="1" height="1"><param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded"/></object>')($scope));

var callback = function(data) {
    //data is an object
    console.log(data.resultFromFireBreath);
}

plugin = document.getElementById("plugin");
plugin.getData(callback);
```

This will have to work for now until someone can figure out how to attach an event to the plugin object after `$compile`.

Comment: Actually using $compile( to append the object is probably a really bad idea; at least in some versions of Chrome it won't work correctly, assuming $compile works the same way jquery's $("html here") functions do; it will create the object tag and set the mimetype before putting it in the dom, which can cause the plugin to be created, destroyed, and then created again. Once you instantiate the plugin (happens when you put the type in) it's not a good idea to move it around. Could be it's working in this version of Chrome (haven't tried recently) but could be you haven't noticed the prob

Comment: Another thing to note is that the reason that the event handling doesn't work the way you expect is that a real javascript event fires with an error object as the parameter; you could do this with FireBreath, but you'd have to create an object that was compatible.  There is a function in there somewhere that makes something almost compatible, but creating an object like that is expensive because it requires several calls across the plugin boundary

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will continue to see if I can attach the object in a different way. AngularJS did put in a fix for $compile for a FB plugin specifically (I had to update to that versions of AngularJS). You are right though about creating and destroying, at different console.log()'s I can get <JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object> and "Type Error". I thought it was weird but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and was able to make the problem go away by creating a read-only `nodeName` property in my plugin object. I asked about this in a firebreath [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/70xKyN4tox4) and taxilian suggested adding this to JSAPIAuto.cpp, which also worked, so I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/pull/120) with the change.

Answer (score 0):

I once spent about 6 hours trying to make FireBreath plugins work with jquery; it was really educational, but ultimately I determined that it wasn't worth the work.

Long story short is that it's not worth it; particularly since even if you could make it work, it would break on IE9 where FireBreath doesn't support addEventListener (IE never gives it the even info, so it's a little hard to support) and you would need to use attachEvent anyway.

Comment: Luckily this only will ever be used in Chrome so I won't need to worry about IE.

Comment: That helps, but it doesn't change that significant work would be required to make firebreath events work through angularjs

Comment: I feel like I am extremely close seeing as how I can get the other functions to work, it is just attaching the event to get the FireBreath event to fire. I see you post on FireBreath a lot so as a side note is there any other way to return to the JS without using an event? I have tried using a JSAPI property but when it prints to the console its blank.

Comment: Heh. I post to FireBreath a lot? I *wrote* firebreath.